# Can a tuple of booleans be matched in guards, like pattern matching?

Tags: haskell, boolean, tuples

I try to make a function that returns different strings, depending on the values in a tuple of boolean

```
chooseAction :: (Bool , Bool , Bool , Bool) -> String 
chooseAction (isJump ,isAcceleration ,isDeceleration ,isSpeedOk) 
        | (True ,False, False, False) = "JUMP"
        | (False ,True, False, False) = "SPEED"
        | (False ,False, True, False) = "SLOW"
        | (False ,False ,False, True) = "WAIT"
```

However this doesn't compile:

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type `Bool'
>             with actual type `(Bool, Bool, Bool, Bool)'
> In the expression: (True, False, False, False)
> In a stmt of a pattern guard for
>                an equation for `chooseAction':
>   (True, False, False, False)
> In an equation for `chooseAction':
>     chooseAction (isJump, isAcceleration, isDeceleration, isSpeedOk)
>       | (True, False, False, False) = "JUMP"
>       | (False, True, False, False) = "SPEED"
>       | (False, False, True, False) = "SLOW"
>       | (False, False, False, True) = "WAIT"
> ```

What am I doing wrong when defining such a function ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The guards expressions must evaluate to be a `Bool` value, but in your case you have tuple of Bools. That is why it is throwing an error

```
Couldn't match expected type `Bool'
            with actual type `(Bool, Bool, Bool, Bool)'
```

You are better off defining the function like this

```
chooseAction::(Bool, Bool, Bool, Bool) -> String
chooseAction (True, False, False, False) = "JUMP"
chooseAction (False, True, False, False) = "SPEED"
chooseAction (False, False, True, False) = "SLOW"
chooseAction (False, False, False, True) = "WAIT"
```

Also, you are not covering all the cases. So, you can cover that like this

```
chooseAction tuple_of_bools = "NONE"
```

If none of the patterns match, then the last one will be executed to get `NONE`. Or, if you want it to be defined like the way it is, then just change the comparison, like this

```
chooseAction:: (Bool, Bool, Bool, Bool) -> String
chooseAction bools
        | bools == (True ,False, False, False) = "JUMP"
        | bools == (False ,True, False, False) = "SPEED"
        | bools == (False ,False, True, False) = "SLOW"
        | bools == (False ,False ,False, True) = "WAIT"
        | otherwise = "NONE"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use pattern matching for this one:

```
chooseAction :: (Bool , Bool , Bool , Bool) -> String 
chooseAction (True ,False, False, False) = "JUMP"
chooseAction (False ,True, False, False) = "SPEED"
chooseAction (False ,False, True, False) = "SLOW"
chooseAction (False ,False ,False, True) = "WAIT"
chooseAction _ = error "This should not happen" -- if sequence is something else
```